# ColdFusion - Displaying rows as columns

Tags: coldfusion

I'm building a scorecard with ColdFusion which will allow for updating data. I need to display the data with the rows as columns and columns as rows. Here is an example of the table:

```
Mon Met1 Met2 Met3 Met2 Met5
Jan 15    24   21   40   50
Feb 30    21   14   39   44
Mar 15    19   20   28   19
Apr 16    31   33   21   43
```

I want to display the data (flipping the rows and columns) like this:

```
Metric Jan  Feb   Mar  Apr

Met1   15   30   15   16  
Met2   24   21   19   31 
Met3   21   14   20   33
Met4   40   39   28   21
Met5   50   44   19   43
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: How many columns max? Can you alter the table structure (ie normalize)? Also, please update the question tags to indicate which database you are using.

Comment: There will may be additions or deletions to the table columns but the rows will remain at 14: Jan - Dec plus GOAL and YTD. The THere will not be any normalization. The tables databse will be MS SQL and or MySQL. THanks

Comment: Are you really using *both* SQL Server and MySQL? Complex features/operators tend to be vendor specific. For example in MS SQL you could use a `pivot`. However, afaik MySQL does not support that yet.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a 'vertical sorting' FAQ I wrote years ago.  Perhaps this will help:

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>Vertical Sorting</title>
</head>
<cfquery name = "qMyQuery" datasource = "dsn">
   SELECT fields
   FROM   table
   ORDER BY myField
</cfquery>
<body>
<!--- set the number of colums you wish to have --->
<cfset cols = 5>
<!--- get the number of rows so you know what record to display at the top of the next row. for example if our query contains "a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m" (13 elements) it will produce 3 totalrows--->
<cfset totalRows = ceiling(qMyQuery.RecordCount / cols)>
<!--- set inital record to 1 "output" is the actual cell of the query --->
<cfset output = 1>
<!--- Create table --->
<table width = "100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing = "2">            
    <!--- loop through the rows.  This loop will run 3 times in this example --->
    <cfloop from = "1" to = "#totalRows#" index = "thisRow">
    <tr>
        <!--- this loop will run 5 times in times in this example --->
        <cfloop from = "1" to = "#cols#" index = "thisCol">
        <!--- the width in the table cell will dynamicaly calculated to evenly distribute the cells. in this example if cols = 5 100/5 will make the cells 20% of the table --->
        <td width = "<cfoutput>#numberformat((100/cols), 99)#</cfoutput>%" align="center" nowrap style = "border: 1px solid #ccc;">
            <!--- Check current record with the record count, this will be used to display data or an empty cell --->
            <cfif output lte qMyQuery.recordCount>
                <cfoutput>#qMyQuery.Mon[output]#</cfoutput>
            <cfelse>
            <!--- use <br> to display an empty cell --->
                <br>
            </cfif>
            <!--- increment counter to the next record in this example if we started on the first cell of the first row it would be 1(a), then 4(d), then 7(g) and so on if this was the firs cell on the second row it would be 2(b), 5(e), 8(h), continue... --->
            <cfset output = output + totalRows>
        </td>
        </cfloop>
        <!--- this little bit tells where to start the next row. if we just finished the first row output would be 2(b) --->
        <cfset output = thisRow + 1>
    </tr>
    </cfloop>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Travis thanks for helping. When I apply this to my sample data I get an error for "undefined" "Mon" in the line: <cfoutput>#qMyQuery.Mon[output]#</cfoutput>. I thought maybe it was Mod but that did not work either. Thanks again.

Comment: meaning... <cfoutput>#qMyQuery.Mon[output]#</cfoutput> is sample code I wrote, you'll need to fill in your own query and column name.

Comment: I've used this countless times but lost the original posting - glad you shared it again here, Travis.