# Displaying data in row in column 1, then rows in column 2, etc

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, coldfusion, lucee

First, I found this solution ([ColdFusion - Displaying rows as columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13201007/coldfusion-displaying-rows-as-columns)) which WOULD fix my problem if I could use `table`, but I can't since this needs to be responsive. However, the client didn't like the responsive tables. They really, **really** would prefer the columns be displayed so the user would only need to scroll up and down, ***and not*** up down and side to side.

I need some help converting the table to bootstrap `<div>`'s. I know the basics: skipping the table,  `tr` equals `div class="row"` and `td` equals `div class="col-sm-*"` stuff. However, more specifically, I'm not sure on the logic to use to convert the SO solution above and how to apply it to my needs.

Using Lucee along side with Bootstrap v3, I'm trying to populate a "grid" but I need to populate the rows in column1 before populating column2.

```
1|10|20|30|40  
2|11|21|31|41  
3|12|22|32|42  
4|13|23|33|43
```

*The code snippet below is from @travis and I take no credit for it*

```
<cfset cols = 5>
<!--- get the number of rows so you know what record to display at the top of the next row. for example if our query contains "a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m" (13 elements) it will produce 3 totalrows--->
<cfset totalRows = ceiling(qMyQuery.RecordCount / cols)>
<!--- set inital record to 1 "output" is the actual cell of the query --->
<cfset output = 1>
<!--- Create table --->
<table width = "100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing = "2">  
<!--- loop through the rows.  This loop will run 3 times in this example --->
    <cfloop from = "1" to = "#totalRows#" index = "thisRow">
    <tr>
        <!--- this loop will run 5 times in times in this example --->
        <cfloop from = "1" to = "#cols#" index = "thisCol">
        <!--- the width in the table cell will dynamicaly calculated to evenly distribute the cells. in this example if cols = 5 100/5 will make the cells 20% of the table --->
        <td width = "<cfoutput>#numberformat((100/cols), 99)#</cfoutput>%" align="center" nowrap style = "border: 1px solid #ccc;">
            <!--- Check current record with the record count, this will be used to display data or an empty cell --->
            <cfif output lte qMyQuery.recordCount>
                <cfoutput>#qMyQuery.Mon[output]#</cfoutput>
            <cfelse>
            <!--- use <br> to display an empty cell --->
                <br>
            </cfif>
            <!--- increment counter to the next record in this example if we started on the first cell of the first row it would be 1(a), then 4(d), then 7(g) and so on if this was the firs cell on the second row it would be 2(b), 5(e), 8(h), continue... --->
            <cfset output = output + totalRows>
        </td>
        </cfloop>
        <!--- this little bit tells where to start the next row. if we just finished the first row output would be 2(b) --->
        <cfset output = thisRow + 1>
    </tr>
    </cfloop>
</table>
```

and this is my attempt to accomplish the same thing using bootstrap:

```
<!-- what I'm working with -->
<cfset cols = 2>
<!-- get the number of rows so you know what record to display at the top of the next row. for example if our query contains "a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m" (13 elements) it will produce 3 totalrows-->
<cfset totalRows = ceiling(qMyQuery.RecordCount / cols)>
<!--- set inital record to 1 "output" is the actual cell of the query --->
<cfset output = 1>
<!--- Create table --->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
    <!--- loop through the rows.  This loop will run 3 times in this example --->
        <cfloop from = "1" to = "#totalRows#" index = "thisRow">
            <div class="row">
                <!--- this loop will run 5 times in this example --->
                <cfloop from = "1" to = "#cols#" index = "thisCol">
                    <div class="col-xs-3" style="border:1px solid red">
                        <cfif output lte qMyQuery.recordCount>
                            <cfoutput>#qMyQuery.mon[output]#</cfoutput>
                        <cfelse>
                            <br>
                        </cfif>
                        <cfset output = output + totalRows>
                    </div>
                </cfloop>
                <cfset output = thisRow + 1>
            </div>
        </cfloop>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, the output from my work simply displays everything in a single full-width page (the inline style of border:1px solid red is there to see what the code is producing). While this is for ColdFusion, the logic for the looping would be the same for PHP I presume.

Any tips, tricks, advice, or preferably solutions to this?

Comment: Bootstrap 3.x uses a base of 12 for its grid system.  If the comment in the code above is correct; "loop will run 5 times", that will create five col-sx-3 divs which adds up to 15.  Another potential problem is that col-sx-3 (in the loop) could be a typo.  The standard grid classes are col-xs-*, col-sm-*, cols-md-*, and col-lg-*.  Of course, the col-sx-3 could be a user-defined class...

Comment: SO wouldn't let me post my code until I fixed some indentations and something else, I forget what it was. I'm familiar with the grid (love it). The sx was a typo, I'll fix that in the code. As for the number of columns, currently set to 2 would need to be dynamic based upon the device being used to view the page. I left it in the code to help explain where the variables and values were but in hind sight believe it may have added confusion instead.

Comment: I've thought of doing some quick math calculations to get the number of records being returned (should be well under 100) and dividing that by the number of columns I would need and then performing a query of queries, for each column of data.

Comment: I don't like the `<div class="row">` then `<div class="col-sm-12">` then `<div class="row">` row pattern. Bootstrap really doesn't work that way.

Comment: @JamesAMohler Are you sure? http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting provides an example on nesting - or is this not what you meant? If not, can you elaborate please?

Comment: I would consider using JavaScript here. Just let ColdFusion output the data to a hidden area of the page, and have JavaScript rearrange it.

Comment: Do you have example code, post, or link you can share?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I had more time, I'd probably do it differently since this is NOT pretty but it did satisfy the requirements and I've spent too much time on this already but most importantly, the client is good with this approach given the budget and time.

For this implementation, the list will never exceed 75 records, will 99% of the time be used on a tablet or larger device, and will be used by users to select checkboxes. There will also be a "select all" option but that is not included in this answer - that's a user story for later.

I'm running three queries (running one query and then a query of queries ), one collecting the first XX number of records, and second XX number of records, XX for the third set of records. I am passing in a variable for the QoQ which will determine how many rows will be displayed so that each column will have some data appear in it.

Then the output looks like this (sorry but I can never get the formatting quite right in SO):

```
`    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-1">
            <cfoutput query="colum1">
                <label><input type="checkbox"> #id# #mon#</label><br/>
            </cfoutput>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <cfoutput query="colum2">
                <label><input type="checkbox"> #id# #mon#</label><br/>
            </cfoutput>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <cfoutput query="colum3">
                <label><input type="checkbox"> #id# #mon#</label><br/>
            </cfoutput>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>`
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what do QoQ's buy you over cfoutput start/endRow?

Comment: Great question. My understanding is that I can cache the original query (which has less than 100 records) and then pull the 25 or so records from the cached memory (caching of cached?). I ran it with and without caching and with and without QoQ (I know these can be expensive). The performance difference was negligible with the QoQ being slightly faster. Perhaps equally as important, the code is readable. LOL.

Comment: If the data does not change frequently, then caching is not a bad idea, but not following how the QoQ's help with the original issue of outputting the data in a specific order, ie down and across instead of across and down.

Comment: @Leigh The MAIN query is ordered by id, then mon. The QoQA will pull the first 25 records from MAIN, the QoQB will pull the next 25 from MAIN, and then the QoQC will pull the remaining 25 from MAIN. Each "set" is in order so that gives me my alphabetical listing in each column. QoQA passes in a value to retrieve 25 records, QoQB and QoQC does the same thing. Then I'm outputting QoQA into ColumnA as defined by the cfoutput query="colum1", cfoutput query="colum2", cfoutput query="colum3".  Does that help?

Comment: The QoQ may not be helping as much as I originally thought. I supposed I could pass in the number of records I need to the CFC as an additional argument... Rethinking this approach.

Comment: The QoQ approach turned out to be better performing and easy to read.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you say that your code is outputting everything in a single column. I tried your example and it seems to be working for me. Are you sure that you have included the bootstrap classes with your page?

I created a ColdFusion gist from your example: https://trycf.com/gist/cec79b0028728c9ec370e3bb8a05991f/lucee5?theme=monokai

The only changes I made were to create a query object with your example data and changed the number of columns (`cols`) to `4` which plays nicely with Bootstraps 12 grid layout system. *You will need to tweak a bit for `5` columns.*

When you run that code it shows the single column of data as you say. But that is because the Bootstrap classes have not been loaded. When I copy the output generated by that code into Bootply it displays correctly in four columns: http://www.bootply.com/a0dF7NKw9V

[image]

Comment: First, thank you for the effort.The code I posted does work, kind of but for my code to work, A) you have to hard code the number of columns B) if the browser is resized, the columns wont stack and C) the list wont be numbers, it'll be text of varying text lengths with a checkbox accompanying the text. HTH. On a desktop, we could have 4 columns, tablet, 3 columns and on a smaller device one column (this is why I can't hard code the `col` variable ahead of time.

Comment: That's what Bootstrap does for you. Basically you need to specify the classes for each device you want. So instead of just specifying `<div class="col-xs-3">` you need to specify something like `<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">`.  That translates to displaying "1 column" for "xs" devices, "3 columns" for "sm" devices and "4 columns" for "md" devices. That should get you heading in the right direction. The tricky part will be trying to display an even number of columns every time.

Comment: _"number of columns every time"_ and there is the problem - LOL.  I think I have a workable solution which I'll post shortly after I finish converting pseudo code to actual code.